# Private Registry with Self Sign certificate for Kubernetes w/o touching Kube nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I created a private registry with self sign certificate for Kubernetes where to pull images from.
What I would like is a way to pull images w/o interacting with Kubernetes nodes.

Is it there a way of doing that?

By default when I'll try to pull images I'll receive `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` so the question is: is it there a way to bypass this w/o importing the CA certificate into trusted certificates on the Kubes nodes?

I do have full access to the Kube via kubeconfig file